# How to reverse a QSlider's range

Tags: c++, qt, qslider

i am stuck at trying to reverse the range of a QSlider such that `abs(maxVal)` always stays on top.

`slider->setRange[0,maxVal]` should look like the slider on the right

`slider->setRange[-maxVal,0]` should be reversed/rotated.

[image]

What i could do is not to reverse the range, set a "-" prefix in the SpinBox above and multiply the value by -1 when reading.
I just wonder if there is the possibility to swap the direction of the slider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to invert the slider, setting the [invertedAppearance property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#invertedAppearance-prop) to `true`:

```
slider->setRange(-maxVal, 0); 
slider->setInvertedAppearance(true);
```